# Why do bootstrap containers not act as block elements and overlap when it surrounds a nav element?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Given the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<nav class = "navbar navbar-nav">
  <div class = "container-fluid" style = "border: solid black">
    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
      <li role = "presentation"><a href= "#"> Grapes </a> </li>
      <li role = "presentation"> <a href= "#"> Apes </a> </li>
      <li role = "presentation"> <a href= "#"> Gapes </a> </li>
      <li role = "presentation"> <a href= "#"> Lapes </a> </li>
      <li role = "presentation"> <a href= "#"> Fapes </a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
<div class = "container-fluid" style = "border: solid yellow">
Some Text
</div>
<script src="../js/jquery2.1.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is why the first div is inside the second div, despite the fact that they are `divs`, a natural block element (should take up the entirety of the horizontal space of the browser)?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can't exactly explain why, but if you swap the first `<nav>` and `<div>` positions it'll produce the expected result: http://www.bootply.com/f1DzG4kWdt

Comment: Actually did that before you said it and got it to work, but was wondering why the flawed version produces the version it does.

Comment: It's part of the CSS of Bootstrap for `.navbar-nav` it looks like. It has `float: left` applied to it; keeping the flawed version and omitting that property produces the expected result as well. http://www.bootply.com/wXkAnggdhw

Comment: Yeah this is definitely part of the answer, but the weird thing is that it is  surrounded by a "container-fluid", so I suppose through some mechanism, overrides the "container-fluid" block property? May be a bug on Bootstrap's part, unless someone tells me otherwise.

Comment: But it's not "surrounded by a `.container-fluid`". :P The `.container-fluid` is inside the `<nav>` element, which has the float applied to it, thus affecting the underlying `<div>` as well. I think you may have your terminology wrong lol

Comment: I meant surrounded `<ul>`. I just realized something, maybe I'll rephrase the question if no one answers, but if you `float: left`  to a `.container-fluid` it will naturally make the element an inline-block element.  `<div class = "container-fluid" style = "border: solid yellow; float:left; height: 100px;">Some Text</div>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117644/discussion-between-rich22-and-tim-lewis).

Comment: Ah, I think I see the issue; `<nav>` element isn't supposed to have the `.navbar-nav` class: `<nav class="navbar navbar-default">` (default Bootstrap example). You have `.navbar-nav` applied to both the `<nav>` and `<ul>` element. See here: http://www.bootply.com/99NdIkbXyk